# M.E.A.N put not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, express, angularjs-scope

I have an array of comments on a picture called 'comments'
I also have a property called "newcmt" that i'd like to push into comments

I have a function addComment that tries and fails to make these changes.

I have tried a few different ways, but the put doesn't seem to update the api despite returning the proper changes in the response.
Am I just updating the reference?
Is asynchronous nature causing errors?
Is my mongo scheme wrong? 
Would it be easier to make comments its own endpoint?

JS

```
var refresh = function() {
  $http.get('/api/things').success(function(awesomeThings) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = awesomeThings;

  });
};


$scope.addThing = function() {
  if($scope.newThing === '') {
    return;
  }
  $http.post('/api/things/', { name: $scope.newThing });

  refresh();
};


$scope.addComment = function(thing) {
  if(thing.newcmt == '') {
    return;
  }
  $scope.newcmt = thing.comment;
  $scope.newcmt.push(thing.newcmt);
  console.log($scope.newcmt)
  $http.put('/api/things/' + thing._id, {comment : $scope.newcmt }, {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true}).success(function(response) {

    console.log(response);
    refresh();

  })
};

$scope.deleteThing = function(thing) {
  $http.delete('/api/things/' + thing._id);
  refresh();
};
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="{{thing.url}}" alt="">
</div>
<div class="col-md-12"  ng-repeat="comment in thing.comment">
  <p>{{comment}}</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
   <i class="fa fa-comment-o fa-3x"></i>
   <input type="text" placeholder='...' ng-model="thing.newcmt" >
   <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="addComment(thing)">+</button>
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-down fa-2x pull-right"></i>
   <i class="fa fa-arrow-up fa-2x pull-right"></i>
   </div>
</div>
```

MODEL

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ThingSchema = new Schema({
name: String,
url: String,
credit: String,
active: Boolean,
comment: Array,
newcmt: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Thing', ThingSchema);
```

PUT

```
exports.update = function(req, res) {
if(req.body._id) { delete req.body._id; }
Thing.findById(req.params.id, function (err, thing) {
if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
if(!thing) { return res.status(404).send('Not Found'); }
var updated = _.merge(thing, req.body);
updated.save(function (err) {
  if (err) { return handleError(res, err); }
  return res.status(200).json(thing);
});
});
};
```

full github:
https://github.com/jneljneljnel/meangen

Comment: Where is your express route handling PUT request in server.

Comment: And why are you doing safe and upsert in javascript ajax call. `$http.put('/api/things/' + thing._id, {comment : $scope.newcmt }, {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true})`

Comment: I've added the express route and the mongo configs were something i found on here that I thought i needed to write to an array